# How can I draw straight line in between nodes in the same x-axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw straight line in between nodes (in the same x-axis) from most left to most right in two-column. I tried to give an example with two nodes in between but there could be more than 2.

my code:

```tex
\documentclass[5p,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
    chains,
    positioning,
    shapes.geometric
}
\begin{document}
\section{Example}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 4mm and 8mm,
        arr/.style = {-Stealth, semithick},
        C/.style = {circle, draw, font=\footnotesize},
        N/.style = {draw, very thick,
                font=\small, align=left,
                inner sep=5pt}
    ]
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (8,2);
    %
    \node (n1) [N] at (0,1) {\$ dummy node \\
        \hphantom{\$ } example};

    \node (n2) [N] at (6,1) {\$ dummy node \\
        \hphantom{\$ } example};

    \draw[very thick] (n1.east)-- (n2.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\newline
\lipsum[-1]
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

Here I was not able to find out most left and most right positons of the line to draw it.

---

wanted output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not completely sure what you want to achieve, but maybe this can help you:

```
\documentclass[5p,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
    chains,
    positioning,
    shapes.geometric
}
\begin{document}
\section{Example}
\noindent  % <-- this is important because (0,0) needs to sit at the start of the column
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        clip,  % <-- prevent line ends to overlap box
        node distance = 4mm and 8mm,
        arr/.style = {-Stealth, semithick},
        C/.style = {circle, draw, font=\footnotesize},
        N/.style = {draw, very thick,
                font=\small, align=left,
                inner sep=5pt}
    ]
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (8,2);
    %
    \node (n1) [N] at (3,1) {\$ dummy node \\
        \hphantom{\$ } example};

    \node (n2) [N] at (6,1) {\$ dummy node \\
        \hphantom{\$ } example};

    \draw[very thick] 
        (0,0 |- n1.west) -- (n1.west)
        (n1.east) -- (n2.west)
        (n2.east) -- (n2.east -| \columnwidth,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\newline
\lipsum[1-1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `(0,0 |- n1.west)` syntax means: the point with the x-coordinate of `(0,0)` and the y-coordinate of `n1.west`.

Comment: Sorry `\lipsum[1-1]` part was unnessesary. I will draw more nodes above the line and below the line so I wanted to split them at start

Comment: Having some `\lipsum` is fine, since it helps to see where the column ends.

Comment: Thanks btw your answer excatly what I was looking for

Comment: If the my nodes drawn little bit left side of the the original grid (or the grid shifted inside) ,(0.0) may not start at the correct place (most left side of the column), could there be fix for that

Comment: It is difficult to catch the actual coordinates where the columns start or end. So, the best would really be that you take `(0,0)` as the leftmost coordinate of the `tikzpicture`. Maybe you can show such an example by editing your question?

Comment: Sure I upadated the code in my question , I just removed `\noindent` before the `tikzpicture`

Comment: No, this is not possible. You need to keep the `\noindent`, because this will shift the `tikzpicture` to the right. You may have in mind something like `[remember picture, overlay]`, but this cannot work here because 1) you only want the `tikzpicture` to shift horizontally and thus need to keep the place and 2) it is very hard to find the absolute coordinate for the start and end of the column.

Comment: Please see the updated Q, I was able to shift the tikzpicture while keeping the `\noindent`. This happens when I locate a node at `(0,1)`

Comment: I still don't quite get what you want. Do you want to shift the picture to the left so that it overlaps the column? then you need to place some negative `\vspace` there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137900/discussion-between-jasper-habicht-and-alper).

Comment: Ok I will use `vspace` . I don't want to shift the picture but it keeps shifting to right :( I will play around to fix this

Answer (score 2):

A small variation of nice @Jasper Habicht answer (+1):

```
\documentclass[5p,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning
                }
\begin{document}
\section{Example}
\noindent  % <-- this is important because (0,0) needs to sit at the start of the column
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4mm and 8mm,
   arr/.style = {-Stealth, semithick},
     C/.style = {circle, draw, font=\footnotesize},
     N/.style = {draw, very thick,
                 font=\small, align=left,
                 inner sep=5pt}
                        ]
\draw[help lines] (0,-1) grid (\columnwidth,1);
    %
\node (n1) [N] at (3,0)     {\$ dummy node \\
                             \hphantom{\$ } example};
\node (n2) [N, right=of n1] {\$ dummy node \\
                             \hphantom{\$ } example};
\draw[very thick]
        (0,0) -- (n1) -- (n2) -- (\columnwidth,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\newline
\lipsum[1-1]
\end{document}
```

[image]